# Angular Material 2: Fix for Multiline Error messages

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I'm using angular material 2 inside my angular application. I'm experiencing a problem when my form input field error messages are more than one line. Here is the photo:

[image: md-error-multiline-bug]

Here is the code:

```
<md-error *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid">
          <span *ngIf="password.errors.required">
                {{'PASSWORD_RECOVERY.FIELD_REQUIRED' | translate}}
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="password.errors.minlength || password.errors.maxlength">
                {{'PASSWORD_RECOVERY.PASSWORD_LENGTH' | translate}}
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="password.errors.pattern">
                {{'PASSWORD_RECOVERY.FOR_A_SECURE_PASSWORD' | translate}}
          </span>
</md-error>
```

I've understood by reading github, that it is a bug in angular 2 material. Did anybody manage to solve this issue by doing a custom workaround?

Comment: Maybe try using `@angular/forms`?

Comment: @Edric what do you mean?

Comment: Can you add code snippet for your formGroup

Comment: @RohanFating here's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xodreuzc/#&togetherjs=NBtMjnh2lK

Comment: Would putting fixed height and overflow hidden work? The plunker is not helpful :(

Comment: @Vega unfortunately no :(

Comment: How did you put? added a class on md-error and also added !important?

Comment: @Vega both to `md-error` and to `span` and with `!important`

Comment: Could you adapt your code to this plunker markup so I can see what's goin on please: https://plnkr.co/edit/7UjV9q5Q5oFaD57xJVel?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154030/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-vega).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the element with class `.mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper` is `position: absolute`, so it's not occupying real space.

As suggested [on this issue on github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4580#issuecomment-340692923) by [xumepadismal](https://github.com/xumepadismal), you can add this scss as workaround that solved my problem:

```
// Workaround for https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4580.
mat-form-field .mat-form-field {
  &-underline {
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  &-subscript-wrapper {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

It transforms the `.mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper` node in a static div, and repositionate the `.mat-form-field-unterline` just after the input field.

Comment: I ended up adding a `overflow: visible;` to `&-subscript-wrapper`, as a `g` character on the bottom line of the message was being cut off.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [in this github discussion](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4580) in Material 15 the problem can be solved by adding subscriptSizing="dynamic" to a mat-form-field.

To change default behavior you have to update angular.module.ts providers with the option:

```js
providers: [
{
      provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
      subscriptSizing: 'dynamic'
      }
    }
]
```

This can also be found in the [Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormField)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `subscriptSizing: 'dynamic'` caused the form fields layout to be messed totally, stretching height along with error messages appearances.

Using the solution proposed by @xumepadismal caused error messages to be pushed too much to the bottom, leaving unnecessary empty space at the top.

With `Tailwind CSS`, this solution worked for me with the latest `Angular 17`:

```scss
.mat-mdc-form-field {
  @apply w-full self-start;

  .mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
    @apply flex;

    .mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper {
      @apply static;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
mat-form-field.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  animation: example;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
@keyframes example {
  from {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

It worked for me.