# Angular material insert mat-hint to custom formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have this custom `FormControl` which holds come complex logic and uses `mat-form-field`.

```js
export class ComplexFormControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor{

    private formControl = new FormControl();

    writeValue(){}
    // Other methods.
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Complex value</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="complex value" [formControl]="formControl">
</mat-form-field>
```

I'm using this component in one of my forms.

```html
<form [form]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
       <mat-label>Simplevalue</mat-label>
       <input matInput placeholder="simple value" formControlName="simple">
    </mat-form-field>
    <complex-form-control-component formControlName="complex"></complex-form-control-component>
</form>
```

Now for example when `form.simple.value === ''` I want to show a hint in the `ComplexFormControlComponent`. I could simply pass the message to `ComplexFormControlComponent` but I'd rather pass a `mat-hint` directly into it.

Something like this:

```html
<complex-form-control-component formControlName="complex">
    <mat-hint *ngIf="form.simple.value === ''">Please enter simple value first</mat-hint>
</complex-form-control-component>
```

How can I do this?

I tried:

```html
<complex-form-control-component formControlName="complex">
    <ng-template><mat-hint>Hint1</mat-hint><ng-template>
    <ng-template><mat-hint>Hint2</mat-hint><ng-template>
</complex-form-control-component>
```

And in the complex component

```js
@ContentChildren(TemplateRef) hints: QueryList<TemplateRef<MatHint>>
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Complex value</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="complex value" [formControl]="formControl">
   <mat-hint>Test</mat-hint>
   <ng-template *ngFor"let hint of hints" [ngTemplateOutlet]="hint"></ng-template>
</mat-form-field>
```

That just places the hint in the `HTML` but the `mat-form-field` does not interact with it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the hint using content projection.
In your component template add the `mat-hint` as the following

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Complex value</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="complex value" [formControl]="formControl">
   <mat-hint>
       <ng-content select="[hint]"></ng-content>
   </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now when using the component you can simply pass the hint like so (notice the attribute "hint" which will be mapped to the ng-content with `select="[hint]"`)

```html
<complex-form-control-component formControlName="complex">
    <ng-container *ngIf="condition" hint> hint </ng-container>
</complex-form-control-component>
```

Comment: What if I have multiple hints?

Comment: <complex-form-control-component formControlName="complex">
    <ng-container hint>
   <ng-container *ngIf="condition1"> hint1 </ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="condition2"> hint2 </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
 </complex-form-control-component>

Comment: That would display one hint with the text `hint1hint2`

Comment: If you want to display each hint in a separate line, well that is not supported by mat-hint, but you can find a workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130916/angular-material-2-fix-for-multiline-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

In your custom component, you can add the `mat-hint` and use the `@Input` to set it from where you use it.

```html
// This is how your component would be. 
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <input matInput
    [name]="formControlName"
    [formControlName]="formControlName"
    [placeholder]="placeholder" 
    [value]="value"
  >
    <mat-hint *ngIf="hint"> {{ hint }} </mat-hint>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your component.ts file, you can add this:

```js
@Input() placeholder: string;
@Input() formControlName: string;
@Input() hint: string;
```

Where you want to use this:

```html
<custom-input 
   [formControlName]="someName" 
   [hint]="'Some hint'"
   [placeholder]="'Some valid placeholder'"
>
</custom-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

To transclude content that relies on logic in the parent component, you should wrap all of that content into one `ng-template`.

Also, you are not projecting it correctly in your child component (`ComplexFormControlComponent`). You should use `ng-container` and put a `[ngTemplateOutlet]` directive on it and pass in the template reference.

See the following example.

```html
// form.html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Simplevalue</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="simple value" formControlName="simple">
    </mat-form-field>

    <complex-form-control>
    <!--  I would wrap all content in one ng-template. -->
        <ng-template>
            <mat-hint *ngIf="form.get('simple').value === ''">
                Hint1
            </mat-hint>
            <mat-hint *ngIf="form.get('simple').value !== ''">
                Hint2
            </mat-hint>
        </ng-template>
    </complex-form-control>
</form>
```

```js
// complex form component
@Component({
  selector: 'complex-form-control',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Complex value</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="complex value" [formControl]="complex">
      <!--  Here is how you output ng-template content -->
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
    </mat-form-field>
  `,
})
export class ComplexFormControlComponent {
  complex = new FormControl();

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Comment: This gives the same result as in my question

Comment: @RobinDijkhof,  what interaction behavior are you expecting the between the `mat-form-field` and the `mat-hint`?

Comment: In the screenshot, i'd exxpect hint1 and hint2 to be like Test.

Comment: This is a css problem then, go look at how material styles `mat-hint` in the docs or on their github. Without looking at the documentation, I'd assume `mat-hint` relies on being a child of `mat-form-field` to be styled how you want.